# Django Adding Comments

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to add a comments section at the end of my form so users can enter comments. I'm following exactly what the Django tutorial is asking: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/example/

But I keep getting this error: 
TemplateSyntaxError 
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'proxy'

Anyone have any idea why? 

Here's the log:

```
91  {% load comments %}
92  {% get_comment_count for form as comment_count %}
93  <p>{{ comment_count }} comments have been posted.</p>
94  {% render_comment_list for form %}
95  
96  {% get_comment_list for form as comment_list %}
97  {% for comment in comment_list %}
98  <p> Posted by: {{ comment.user_name }} on {{ comment.submit_date }}</p>
99  
100 <p>Comment: {{ comment.comment }}</p>
101 {% endfor %}
```

The error occurs at line 92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag requires a model instance, not a form.

Comment: I've actually just figured out that much.. I just can't seem to define  what my instance would be.
Can you define model instance? with a simple example perhaps? Maybe that will help clarify things for me.. Thanks a ton

Comment: Sure, though considering your other question you might have figured this out. If you define a model in your models.py, you 'instantiate' it by constructing an object from the class (`p = Post(title="My Blog Post`)) and write it to the database by calling save (`p.save()`).

Comment: To fiddle with models as if you were the framework, try `./manage.py shell`, where you can import your models, save them, etc, and see what I'm talking about. You get access to these in a template through a `RequestContext` object, returned from a view. And if you haven't already, you might want to consider going through the full Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)- it covers most of this stuff pretty thoroughly.